# Encrypt file in python with aes, then decrypt file in Android

Tags: java, python, android, encryption, aes

I have been encrypted file in Python, decrypted file in Android (JAVA). But the decrypted file is not available.
I use AES/CBC. The decrypted MD5 is different from the original file, and decrypted file is not available.

This is my python code that used in encrypt.

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib

class AESCipher:
    MODE = AES.MODE_CBC
    KEY_BYTES = 32
    BLOCK_SIZE = AES.block_size
    SEGMENT_SIZE = 128

    def __init__(self, key: str):
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt_file(self, file_path, output_path):
        '''
        Encrypt file
        '''
        chunk_size = 64 * 1024
        files_ize = str(os.path.getsize(file_path)).zfill(16)
        IV = Random.new().read(self.BLOCK_SIZE)

        encryptor = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV, segment_size=self.SEGMENT_SIZE)

        with open(file_path, 'rb') as infile:
            with open(output_path, 'wb') as outfile:
                outfile.write(files_ize.encode('utf-8'))
                outfile.write(IV)

                while True:
                    chunk = infile.read(chunk_size)

                    if len(chunk) == 0:
                        break

                    elif len(chunk) % self.BLOCK_SIZE != 0:
                        chunk += b' ' * (self.BLOCK_SIZE - (len(chunk) % self.BLOCK_SIZE))

                    outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

This is my Android code that used in decrypt.

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AESCipher {
    private static final String AES_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM    = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION       = "AES/CBC/NoPadding";
    private static final String MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM    = "SHA-256";
    private static final String ENCODING                    = "UTF-8";

    private static final String KEY_STR = "password";
    private static final int IV_SIZE = 16;
    private static byte[] KEY;

    private static AESCipher instance = null;

    AESCipher() {
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(MESSAGE_DIGEST_ALGORITHM);
            messageDigest.update(KEY_STR.getBytes(ENCODING));
            KEY = messageDigest.digest();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static AESCipher getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AESCipher();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    
    public void DecryptFileFromAsset(Context context, String fileName, String outputName) {
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
            int encryptedFileSize = (int) assetFileDescriptor.getLength();

            // load file
            InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(fileName);

            // get file size
            byte[] fileSizeBytes = new byte[16];
            inputStream.read(fileSizeBytes);
            int fileSize = Integer.parseInt(new String(fileSizeBytes));

            // get IV
            byte[] ivBytes = new byte[IV_SIZE];
            inputStream.read(ivBytes);

            // initialize AES cipher
            IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
            SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, AES_ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_TRANSFORMATION);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);
            
            ByteArrayOutputStream decryptedBytesBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] encryptedBytes = new byte[64 * 1024];

            while (inputStream.read(encryptedBytes) != -1) {
                decryptedBytesBuffer.write(cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes));
            }

            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + outputName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutputStream.write(decryptedBytesBuffer.toByteArray(), 0, fileSize);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the Python code runs at all. For CBC, the `segment_size` parameter is not defined and generates a corresponding exception: `Unknown parameters for CBC: {'segment_size': 128}`. Also, why are you using padding with blanks? This should not be the cause of the error, but it is unreliable. And _PyCryptodome_ supports padding in a dedicated module.

Comment: Ew. Just encode integers as big endian values instead of stringifying them. Error is probably in the Java `read`, where you ignore how many bytes are put into the `encryptedBytes` buffer; you only compare with -1.